# How to tag launch template _itself_ in AWS with JSON and `create-launch-template` AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

While creating EC2 launch templates with the `create-launch-template` AWS CLI `ec2` command and a JSON spec, I can't seem to figure out how to tag the template itself. I'm providing the `TagSpecifications` correctly, because I can see the tags being applied to the resources when the launch template is used, but I want to tag the template itself, too.

I tried adding a `Tags` field to the JSON description of the launch template, that gave an error.
The docs suggest using a `TagSpecification` object like so:

```
{
  "ResourceType": "launch-template",
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "mykey", 
      "Value": "myvalue"
    }
  ]
}
```

... (note the "launch-template" resource type) which runs just fine without erring, but the template gets created without any tags :-/

I could run some follow-up tagging statements, but I'm trying to avoid doing that, and [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/amazon-ec2-now-supports-tagging-launch-templates-on-creation/) suggests it's doable at creation-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have followed the AWS-CLI example from [Creating a launch template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html#create-launch-template) and it was indeed created with the tag associated.

This is the command I used:

```
aws ec2 create-launch-template \
    --launch-template-name TemplateForWebServer \
    --version-description WebVersion1 \
    --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=launch-template,Tags=[{Key=purpose,Value=production}]' \
    --launch-template-data file://template-data.json
```

And this is the created launch template:

[image]

What's your AWS-CLI version? Perhaps it's too old. Mine is:

```
~ $ aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.97 Python/3.6.9 Linux/5.4.0-52-generic botocore/1.17.20
```

Comment: `aws-cli/2.0.57 Python/3.9.0 Darwin/19.3.0 source/x86_64` ... but I notice you're providing `--tags-specifications` separately from `--launch-template-data`. In my case, I placed by tag specifications in the JSON spec (in the `tagSpecifications` field, as described in the documentation). I wonder if that's the difference?

Comment: @mmuurr it kind of makes sense - the template is the *resource* you want tagged and the tags are *external* to that resource, hence it makes sense that they are specified in a separate parameter. Give it a try this way and see if it helps. If it does accept the answer please to tick it off as solved. Thanks

Comment: yeah that worked, though the AWS CLI docs suggest either would work, and it doesn't even make sense that a EC2 Launch Template would tag a downstream EC2 Launch Template, as I don't think(?) they can create 'themselves', but :shrug:. In any case, thanks for the idea!